# Return index value as string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to return the index of a value as a string.  Other questions on here that I saw had it return indexes as lists.

The error that is thrown is:
 You returned a variable of type  and we expected a type of

My code:

```
String_to_be_returned=(df['Column'].index[df['Column']==2])
```

Example:

When I print String_to_be_returned, I get this:

Index(['United States'], dtype='object', name='Country Name')

Comment: I'd suggest to add example with input and output

Answer (score 19):

I think you need add `[0]` for select first value of `index` which is `array`:

```
String_to_be_returned= df[df['Column']==2].index[0]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column':[1,2,3],
                   'Column1':[4,5,6]
                   }, index=['Slovakia','United States','Mexico'])

print (df)
               Column  Column1
Slovakia            1        4
United States       2        5
Mexico              3        6

String_to_be_returned= df[df['Column']==2].index[0]
print (String_to_be_returned)
United States
```

---

```
String_to_be_returned= df.index[df['Column']==2][0]
print (String_to_be_returned)
United States
```